# Variable is undefined after assignment on JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is getting frustrating, variable is always undefined after assignment. Please explain what I am doing wrong here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitButton").click(function() {
        var startDate = $('#startDate').val();
        var endDate = $('#endDate').val();

        if (!isDate(startDate) && !isDate(endDate))
        {
            alert ('Start Date and End Date is invalid');
            return false;
        }
        ... other condition removed for clarity
    });
});

function isDate(dateText)
{
    var comp = [];
    var comp2 = '';
    var y_length = 0;

    comp = dateText.split('/');
    comp2 = comp[2];
    y_length = comp2.length;

    //invalid if year length is less than or greater than 4 
    if (y_length < 4 || y_length > 4) {
        return false;
    }

    var m = parseInt(comp[0], 10);
    var d = parseInt(comp[1], 10);
    var y = parseInt(comp[2], 10);

    var date = new Date(y, m - 1, d);

    if (date.getFullYear() == y && date.getMonth() + 1 == m && date.getDate() == d) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I amg getting '**Cannot read property length of undefined**' on line **y_length assignment**, this line:

```
//comp2 here is undefined
y_length = comp2.length;
```

Additionally, do you have any suggestion on date validation using JavaScript. Thank you.

Comment: What is the value of `dateText` in the argument of the function? Maybe is better if you share us a snippet in jsfiddle :)

Comment: Apart from typo in `y_lenth > 4` your code should work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/q9j69zs5/.

Comment: You are essentially assigning `undefined` to it in `comp2 = comp[2]`, if the argument dateText does not have at least 2 `/` at where to split.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: Or better yet, a Stack Snippet here on site.

Comment: dateText value is 08/07/2015, the weird thing here is when I alert(comp2) after the assignment of comp2 it will alert 2015, after that line, comp2 will be undefined. This is weird!

Comment: *"when I alert(comp2) after the assignment of comp2 it will alert 2015, after that line, comp2 will be undefined"* Not with the code above it won't. This is one of the several reasons why `alert`-style debugging has been obsolete for several years. Don't use `alert` or `console.log`, **use a debugger!** :-) There's a fully-featured one built into your browser. Set a breakpoint on that line, and single-step through.

Comment: @jomsk1e what you're describing does not make sense. The only way a variable can change between two lines is if another thread is updating it - but in this case the variable is private to the method. Reproduce this in jsfiddle, and im sure you'd get an answer, but as it stands this is unanswerable.

Comment: alright I get it now! Sorry for wasting all your time and of course thank you! What triggers the undefined is not the startDate but the endDate! I am thinking that startDate is the one producing it!! Geez, I need some sleep! Thanks guys!

Comment: Apart of your error, are you considering to use some library to date manipulation? I recommend you `Moment.js` that's simple and easy to use. you can manipulate, comparate, create, and much more with dates. Take a look at http://momentjs.com . Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If dateText doesn't have at least 2 instances of / in it you are going to end up with less than 3 elements after the split so

```
comp2 = comp[2];
```

sets comp2 to undefined and

```
y_length = comp2.length;
```

will error out. If you are entering a dateText which has 2 (or more instances) of / in it you shouldn't be getting this error. If you are, you will want to check the value of dateText (with an alert or console.log)

You might want to do something like

```
if (comp.length > 2) {
    comp2 = comp[2];
    ...
else {
    // error handling
    ...
```

Comment: sure, that's right. But I am sure that comp[2] has a value, in fact I tried to alert(comp2) right after the assignment and it shows me the value. After that comp2 become undefined

Comment: @jomsk1e can you show a `console.log()` of the value in every step?

Comment: if I will put console.log(comp2) right after the assignment of comp2, the value is 2015, and after that it will become undefined.

Comment: @jomsk1e - do check if there are 2 instance of this particular bit of script in your code. The place where it's console.logging may not be exact place where its showing an error. I've copy pastaed errors like that too many times :-)

Comment: thank you potatopeelings, the one producing the error is the endDate, and I'm thinking startDate is producing it. I need to use error handling like the one you suggested, so I am accepting your answer! THank you! I need some sleep XD